# I get RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 Exception with drawing polygons in flutter google maps

Tags: flutter, dart, maps

I am new to flutter and dart. I got this code from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_polyline_points#-example-tab-) but when I run it it gives me this error

> Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is
>   empty: 0

I caught the lines which caused the exception

```
 _getPolyline()async
  {
   try{ List<PointLatLng> result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(googleAPiKey,
        _originLatitude, _originLongitude, _destLatitude, _destLongitude);


    if(result.isNotEmpty){
      result.forEach((PointLatLng point){
        polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });


    }
    }catch(e){
      print('exception is $e');
    }
    _addPolyLine();
  }
```

The complete code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MapScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {

  GoogleMapController mapController;
  double _originLatitude = 6.5212402, _originLongitude = 3.3679965;
  double _destLatitude = 6.849660, _destLongitude = 3.648190;
  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = {};
  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polylines = {};
  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
  String googleAPiKey = "api key";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    /// origin marker
    _addMarker(LatLng(_originLatitude, _originLongitude), "origin", BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker);
    /// destination marker
    _addMarker(LatLng(_destLatitude, _destLongitude), "destination", BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(90));
    _getPolyline();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          body: GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(_originLatitude, _originLongitude),
                zoom: 15
            ),
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
            compassEnabled: true,
            scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
            zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
            polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polylines.values),
          )
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async
  {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  _addMarker(LatLng position, String id, BitmapDescriptor descriptor)
  {
    MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(id);
    Marker marker = Marker(markerId: markerId, icon: descriptor, position: position);
    markers[markerId] = marker;
  }

  _addPolyLine()
  {
    PolylineId id = PolylineId("poly");
    Polyline polyline = Polyline(
        polylineId: id,
        color: Colors.red, points: polylineCoordinates
    );
    polylines[id] = polyline;
    setState(() {
    });
  }

  _getPolyline()async
  {
   try{ List<PointLatLng> result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(googleAPiKey,
        _originLatitude, _originLongitude, _destLatitude, _destLongitude);


    if(result.isNotEmpty){
      result.forEach((PointLatLng point){
        polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });


    }
    }catch(e){
      print('exception is $e');
    }
    _addPolyLine();
  }

}
```

I have enabled the all the relevant apis(maps,geo,directions) api in my google account. What might be the problem?

Comment: i think problem is in body where you are providing makers and polylines. because initially polylines and makers are empty and you are assigning to widget's property. check those property over their are empty or not and if not empty then give those variables to respect properties.

Comment: how do i do it?

Comment: I know it sounds stupid but have you updated the `googleAPiKey` correctly?

Comment: Yes i have updated the api